# PrincipalPermission.Demand() failing once WCF Service was moved to SSL

Tags: silverlight, wcf, principalpermission

My Silverlight/WCF application uses PrincipalPermission in each service method to ensure the user is Authenticated.  This works just fine when I have everything configured to HTTP, but once I configured my service endpoints/bindings to support HTTPS (SSL), I get an exception thrown when I call the Demand() method of my PrincipalPermission object.

**EDIT:  I should mention I am using IIS 7.5 Express to host and debug this project.**

Here is the method that checks to make sure the user is authendicated.  It's called from each of my service methods:

```
 protected void SecurityCheck(string roleName, bool authenticated)
{
  System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

  PrincipalPermission p = new PrincipalPermission(null, roleName, authenticated);
  try
  {
    p.Demand();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) 
  {        
    /* wrap the exception so that Silverlight can consume it */        
    ServiceException fault = new ServiceException() 
    {                 
      /* Code = 1 will mean "unauthenticated!" */                 
      Code = 1, Message = ex.Message 
    }; 
    throw new FaultException<ServiceException>(fault); }
}
```

}

The execption thown is "Request for principal failed."

Here are the important bits of my web.config file:

```
<behavior name="BinarySSL">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00"/>
        </behavior>
<binding name="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService.customBinding0" 
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpsTransport  authenticationScheme="Basic"/>
        </binding>
<service name="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService"  behaviorConfiguration="BinarySSL">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService.customBinding0"
          contract="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService" />        
      </service>
```

Here is the ClientConfig:

```
<binding name="CustomBinding_ProjectService">
                        <binaryMessageEncoding />
                        <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  />
                    </binding>

    <endpoint address="https://localhost:44300/Services/ProjectService.svc"
                    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ProjectService"
                    contract="ProjectProxy.ProjectService" name="CustomBinding_ProjectService" />
```

I'm hoping someone can point in in the right direction here.  **Again, this configuration works just fine until I configure my services for SSL**.  Any thoughts?

Thanks,

-Scott

---

I thought I found the problem, and answered my own question - but I was wrong.  Still have the same issue.